# Too deep crawlspace?

Tags: foundation

I recently had my crawlspace inspected due to an issue with a bulging floor. That has been solved, but the inspector warned me that my crawlspace was at some point dug out down to the bottom of the foundation blocks. He told me that hydrostatic pressure would eventually destroy the walls. Other than diverting as much water away from the house as possible, is there anything else I can do? Can I slowly add a dry substrate to fill it back up to the proper depth? Or are there braces that I can place? Thank you.

Comment: Some photos would help

Comment: I don't understand the "hydrostatic pressure would eventually destroy the walls" comment.  Does he mean hydrostatic pressure from the outside will try to force the wall inward?

Comment: Qualifications of the "inspector?" Houses with dirt-floored basements have sat on cellar walls "dug out to the bottom" on the inside for centuries - sounds like the end result of feeding a bull from here...

Comment: When I had a crawl space leak, it was bad enough to dig around the stem wall and to the footing. Then installed a perforated (NOT ADS, it gets plugged up) drain pipe with drain rock and a fabric lining.  Then the contractor sprayed tar on the stem wall and then installed something called Delta Dimple mat. That was 15 years ago and haven't had a problem since.   Still, you have to know where the water is coming from to properly mitigate it.

Comment: This question isn't clear. What are "foundation blocks"? A foundation wall isn't required to be buried. If we're talking about _footings_, the specific configuration is needed.

Comment: My interpretation is that OP was referring to the crawl space wall, not the footers.  Aren't footers usually poured concrete?  Then the foundation wall (blocks or poured concrete or some other method) built on top of the poured footer?

Comment: Yes, but footings could plausibly be described as "blocks" by the ignorant. Let's not speculate, mm-kay? :)

Comment: I haven't seen them @SteveSh, but I'm betting the footers (or whatever passes for footers) under my house, built in the 1890s aren't poured concrete...

Answer (score 1):

A picture would help tremendously, so I will try to catch the possibilities. If there is a foot of dirt against the outside wall, and the dirt on the inside is down to the bottom of the block... the same as the top of the foundation. IMO, there should be no concern. If the dirt is higher on the outside, say 3 or 4 feet, it draws a bit more concern. If it is more than that something may need to be done.

This is if it is a BLOCK wall and not a poured concrete wall on top of the foundation. If it is a block wall, it could be filled with concrete to satisfy building code rules for earthquake requirements. All these details will effect how the wall acts to outside (hydrostatic) pressure. Poured concrete, or reinforced block walls will hold back the pressure better than a simple block wall.